# Error when trying to implement a function declared in a supertrait

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to implement a trait that has a supertrait, like so:

```rust
trait A {
    fn do_a(&self);
}

trait B: A {
    fn do_b(&self);
}

struct S {}

impl B for S {
    fn do_a(&self) {}
    fn do_b(&self) {}
}
```

When I run cargo build I get these compiler errors:

```
error[E0407]: method `do_a` is not a member of trait `B`
  --> src/example.rs:12:5
   |
12 |     fn do_a(&self) {}
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a member of trait `B`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `example::S: example::A` is not satisfied
  --> src/example.rs:11:6
   |
5  | trait B: A {
   |          - required by this bound in `example::B`
...
11 | impl B for S {
   |      ^ the trait `example::A` is not implemented for `example::S`
```

I keep re-reading about supertraits, but I'm having trouble understanding this error.

- The first error seems to contradict what `trait B: A` is telling the program to do.
- The second error seems to contradict that the implementation of `do_a(&self) {}` satisfies `A`.

What am I missing here? Is my mental model wrong, or is my code missing some necessary boilerplate, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the syntax is more about bounding the type (e.g. a type `T` that implements `B` *must* necessarily implement `A`) than inheritance in the object-oriented sense. If you write out the `impl`s separately it compiles fine:

```rust
trait A {
    fn do_a(&self);
}

trait B: A {
    fn do_b(&self);
}

struct S {}

impl A for S {
    fn do_a(&self) {}
}

impl B for S {
    fn do_b(&self) {}
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c1c79718e67674a5a418861f21cafd13)

N.B. that if you remove the `impl` for `A` the code no longer compiles, the constraint that an `impl` of `B` must also `impl A` is no longer satisfied.